# How to access manually created SmartArt objects through VBA in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

SmartArt objects that are manually created (i.e. through the GUI) in Microsoft Word do not show up in the ActiveDocument.Shapes collection. I.e. if I start with a blank document, and then manually create a SmartArt with some content in it, and then call ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count - it returns 0.

However, if I create the SmartArt using VBA as such, then it shows up in the ActiveDocument.Shapes collection.

```
Dim myShape As shape
Dim mySmartArt As SmartArt

Set myShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddSmartArt(Application.SmartArtLayouts(1), 100, 100, 400, 400)
    Set mySmartArt = myShape.SmartArt
```

So far I have not been able to find any resources that point me in the direction of accessing SmartArt shapes in Word through VBA.

I have tried using the 'Record Macro' function to generate the VBA it runs when I create the SmartArt manually, however, this simply returns a blank macro.

Any insights would be appreiciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserted via the ribbon you can access the smart art through `InlineShapes` collection

You can "migrate" them to "normal" shapes like this and then access them as you expect it.

```vb
Sub convertInlineSmartArtToShape()

Dim iShp As InlineShape
For Each iShp In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
    If iShp.HasSmartArt Then
        iShp.ConvertToShape
    End If
Next

End Sub
```